# Expected value of a minimum

Tags: probability

> Under a group insurance policy, an insurer agrees to pay 100% of the medical bills incurred during the year by employees of a company, up to a max of $1$ million dollars. The total bills incurred, $X$, has pdf
>   $$
> f_X(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{x(4-x)}{9}, & \text{for } 0 < x < 3\\
> 0& \text{else}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   where $x$ is measured in millions. Calculate the total amount, in millions of dollars, the insurer would expect to pay under this policy.

So I was able to obtain part of the solution, which was
$$
E(\min(X,1)) = \int_0^1 x\cdot \frac{x(4-x)}{9} dx \tag1
$$

However, the solution has $(1)$, plus 
$$
E(\min(X,1)) = \int_1^3 1\cdot \frac{x(4-x)}{9} dx \tag2
$$

What I don't understand is if the problem explicitly states that they agree to pay *up to* $1$ million, why would you even have to bother with $(2)$?

Comment: The minimum function is $x$ for $x\lt 1$ and $1$ for $1\lt x\le 3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For amounts greater than one million, they still pay out a million.

Let $x$ be the total bills in millions. For $x \in [0,1]$ the payout is $x$, for $x \in [1,\infty)$, the payout is $1$. Hence the payout as a function of $x$ is $p(x) = \min(x,1)$, and you wish to compute $Ep$.
\begin{eqnarray}
Ep &=& \int_0^\infty p(x) f_X(x) dx \\
&=& \int_0^1 x f_X(x) dx + \int_1^3 1 f_X(x)dx  + \int_3^\infty 1 f_X(x)dx \\
&=& \frac{13}{108} + \frac{22}{27}+ 0 \\
&=& \frac{101}{108}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: The third integrand should be $1\cdot0$ rather than $0f_X(x)$ (for the same net result, of course).

Comment: @Did: Thanks for catching that. I tripped myself. My first calculation omitted the last integral...

Comment: You are welcome. Nice answer, straight to the heart of the matter.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm having trouble with a similar situation in this problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524217/expectation-of-induced-distribution